# Unable to retrieve firebase realtime database and show it in recycler view

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

regiesteredComplaints.java

```
public class regiesteredComplaints extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference ref;
    FirebaseAuth mauth;
    FirebaseUser user;
    RecyclerView recyc;
    complaintAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_regiestered_complaints);
        recyc = findViewById(R.id.idRVComplaints);
        recyc.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mauth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user = mauth.getCurrentUser();
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://muskan-cba1b-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/");

     //   https://muskan-cba1b-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/


        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Datamodel> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Datamodel>()
                        .setQuery(database.getReference("Users").child(user.getUid()).child("Complaints"),Datamodel.class)
                        .build();

        adapter = new complaintAdapter(options);
        recyc.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

DataModel.java

```
package com.example.muskan;

import com.google.firebase.database.PropertyName;

public class Datamodel {
   private String name,age,sort,image;
    private long complaintID;
    public Datamodel() {
    }


    public Datamodel(String name, String age, String sort, String image, Long complaintID) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.sort = sort;
        this.image = image;
        this.complaintID = complaintID;
    }

    @PropertyName("name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    @PropertyName("name")

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @PropertyName("age")
    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @PropertyName("age")
    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @PropertyName("sort")
    public String getSort() {
        return sort;
    }

    @PropertyName("sort")
    public void setSort(String type) {
        this.sort = type;
    }

    @PropertyName("image")
    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    @PropertyName("image")
    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    @PropertyName("complaintID")
    public long getComplaintID() {
        return complaintID;
    }

    @PropertyName("complaintID")
    public void setComplaintID(Long complaintID) {
        this.complaintID = complaintID;
    }
}
```

complaintAdapter.java

```
public class complaintAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Datamodel,complaintAdapter.myviewholder> {


    public complaintAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Datamodel> options) {
        super(options);

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.complaint_rv_item,parent,false);
        return new myviewholder(view);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myviewholder holder, int position, @NonNull Datamodel model) {

        holder.name.setText(model.getName());
        holder.age.setText(model.getAge());
        holder.type.setText(model.getSort());
        holder.id.setText((int) model.getComplaintID());
        Glide.with(holder.img.getContext()).load(model.getImage()).into(holder.img);
    }

    static class myviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView img;
        TextView name,age,type,id;
        public myviewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            img=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagerv);
            name=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.namerv);
            age=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.agerv);
            type=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.typerv);
            id=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.complaintIDrv);    
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Here is my Firebase Realtime Database]

The setter methods in my DataModel class are not used by the firebaseRecyclerMethods while retrieving firebase realtime database into recycler view. I think problem is this. I also observed that the constructor of DataModel class are never used.

Comment: This sounds like an elaboration of the same [problem you posted before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73373015/is-it-the-correct-method-to-retrieve-the-complaints-reference-in-the-attached-fi). Is there a specific reason why you didn't edit your previous question with the additional information as I suggested there? Reposting the same problem multiple times may get you banned from using the site.

Comment: Oh! I didnt know that earlier. Actually there was so much to edit...so I thought to post the new one

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance, and the properties in your `Datamodel` class seem to match the names in the database. If you set a breakpoint in `onBindViewHolder` and run in the debugger, does it ever reach that breakpoint? If so, what does `model` look like? Also: does this happen when you compile in debug mode, or only in release mode?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.